# Splitting a string with complex characters sequences in C++/CLI

Tags: .net, split, c++-cli

I have the following string below that is causing me a lot of grief.

```
"John","\Jane","\Jerry"
```

The declaration in Visual C++ for the above string is as follows:

```
String ^mynames="John\",\"\\\Jane\",\"\\Jerry";
```

The problem is I am not able to split each name by the characters `","\`.
I need to store the result in an array:

```
array<String^>^ data_line;
```

But the following line doesn't work

```
data_line=mynames->Split('\",\"\\\');
```

Comment: Is this exact code you used?

Comment: @user2623967 Yes.. but I just edited the variable name so it was consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well here's a working solution in Visual C++ CLI/Managed C++.

The split function did not accept splitting a string directly against a set of characters inputted by a user.
To resolve this a String array needs to be declared and passed to the split function.
A bit silly and tedious but here is a working code sample.

```
String ^mynames="John\",\"\\\Jane\",\"\\Jerry";
array<String^>^ data_line;
array<String^>^ stringtocompare = gcnew array<String^>(1);  //Declare an array to do the comparison
stringtocompare[0]="\",\"\\";       //Compare against the character sequence ","\
data_line=mynames->Split(stringtocompare, StringSplitOptions::None);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't get a compiler error, your code reverted to `String.Split(Char[])`, with accepts `"`, `,`, `"` and `\` as separators.

You need to use `","\` as separator, so use:

```
data_line=test->Split(new string[] {"\",\"\\\"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Comment: This is not managed c++ code.In particular new string[]. But thanks you put me on the right track.
I've attached a working solution as an answer in c++ with your help. Thanks